# How to write in .csv format when output is a list with unequal sizes list components in R

Tags: r, csv

I am working with a R program whose output is a list of size n and each components is also a list of unequal sizes. Here is  sample, let M is a list (with n=3) whose components are given below

> M<-

```
[[1]][[1]]
     [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 0.37129   0.90591
[2,] 0.41116   0.91866
[3,] 0.45105   0.93140
[4,] 0.46855   0.88944
[5,] 0.42869   0.87671
[6,] 0.38884   0.86396

[[1]][[2]]
     [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 0.46855 0.88944
[2,] 0.50844 0.90215

[[2]][[1]]
[3,] 0.52595 0.86020
[4,] 0.48609 0.84750

[[3]][[1]]
     [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 0.23322 0.25205
[2,] 0.27293 0.26451
[3,] 0.29221 0.21904
```

Question: How to write this output list (here, M) to a single csv file?

Comment: Check `?capture.output`  Or may be you need to make a single matrix out of `M`, by `do.call(rbind,..)` and then use `write.csv/write.table`

Comment: Why do you want to write this to a CSV? A CSV is usually used for data in table format.

Comment: @Roland. Thanks for your attention. I want to CSV because I want to store the output for future work. It involve big data size (well large for me).

Comment: @akrun Thanks for attention. I am trying with your suggestion.

Comment: @janak You could collapse this in to a single matrix and add an index variable to account for the list element where it came from For example `res <- do.call(rbind, do.call(c, M))`

Comment: Why do you want to store as CSV then? Use `saveRDS`.

Comment: @akrun Your second suggestion is working fine...Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by arun you can put this specific list into a matrix.

But as you want to save a big object for further use in R you should definitely use:

```
     save(myObject, file="myObject.rda")
```

You can then load it with:

```
     load("myObject.rda")
```

This has several advantages over .csv :

1) it is smaller on disk

2) it is faster to save and load

3) you will get immediately the structure of the object you saved, whatever this structure is

Comment: I think in your second code you wanted to write "load("myObject.rda")".